# LTFT high and never changes

Tags: hyundai, santa-fe, fuel-trims

Santa Fe 2001 2.7 GLS.  LTFT is always +18 on both banks, never changes at any RPM.
STFT +4 to +6 Bank 1 and +3 to +5 banks 2 at idle.
At higher rpms STFT hangs around Zero but goes up when engine returns to idle.
LTFT never moves from +18.

Comment: What *exactly* is your question here?

Comment: if you don't have a scan tool that can reset the adaptives, disconnect your battery cables and short them against each other for a few minutes. go for a test drive and see if the fuel trims reset back to +18. Are there any codes?

Comment: My question is quiet obvious...why does the LTFT stay at +18?

Comment: Thanks Ben...I have a brand new Actron CP9670, still become familiar with it.  If this machie can do it could you please tell me how to reset the adaptives? Sometime I find a P0171 and/or P0174 but no check light.

Comment: your going to have to disconnect the battery cables i don't think your actron will work you need a near oe level scantool to reset adaptives.

Comment: Hi Ben: What are adaptives?

Comment: I scanned another car and both LT and ST setteld around Zero. Re-scanned Santa Fe and now, LT is around Zero +.08 and +.04 but ST is +14 ands +16, at all RPM. Does this make any sense?